# How to concatenate code from two variables

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Let's say I have these 2 variables:

```
const test1 = (<div> ..... </div>);
const test2 = (<div> ..... </div>);
```

How do I combine them together (meaning - the code of `test1` followed by the code of `test2`) into a "valid" variable called `test3` and then render it like:

```
{this.array.length !== 0 ? test3 : null}
```

?

Comment: That - "const test3 = test1 + test2;" ?

Comment: That didn't work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using React 16.2+, use a [Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html):

```
{this.array.length !== 0 ? <React.Fragment>{test1}{test2}</React.Fragment> : null}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! (Will accept the answer in 8 minutes haha)

Comment: If your config supports it (I know the latest creat-react-app does) you can also do


`<><div>...</div><div>...</div></>`


and it is equivalent. Not that it makes a difference, just so you know the newer syntax if you see it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a React Fragment in combination of short-circuit syntax to get it short and sweet.

```
render() {
  const test3 = <React.Fragment>{test1}{test2}</React.Fragment>;
  return (this.array.length && test3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it even shorter by doing this if you're using latest versions of React. Don't have to type React.Fragment ;) The shorthand is <> and

```
const test3 = {this.array.length !== 0 ? <>{test1}{test2}</> : null }
```